# SAS logical operators help (if at least two are true then...)

Tags: sas

SAS question.  I am creating a variable where if different logic rules are met it takes on one of two values. Let's say the binary variable I'm creating is RiskScore and there are three conditions A, B, and C that determine which risk score an observation takes on. How would I do this in SAS?

Condition A: Age > 70
Condition B: Cholesterol > 200
Condition C: Has diabetes

If at least two of conditions A, B, or C are TRUE then RiskScore=High;
Else RiskScore=Low;

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SAS true/false are 1/0, so if you add up your conditions and it's greater than 
or equal to 2 then you're good to go.

```
 if sum(age>70, chol>200, diabetes=1)>=2 then do;
```